# Get a collection of all the DataRows coresponding to selected DataGridView rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a direct way to do this, or do I need to iterate over the DataGridView.SelectedRows, and then access DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem for each row to create one?

Comment: That sounds pretty direct to me.

Comment: A hypothetical DataGridView.GetSelectedRowsInDataSource method would've been more direct than writing the method myself.  Better to ask a silly question than to make a maintenance programmer question my competence for rewriting the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataGridView does not provide a SelectedDataRows and SelectedRows in not Linq-enabled, so Yes, you will have to write a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

A generic extension method to add "SelectedDataRows" to DataGridViews:

```
public static T[] SelectedDataRows<T>(this DataGridView dg) where T : DataRow
{
    T[] rows = new T[dg.SelectedRows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < dg.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
        rows[i] = (T)((DataRowView)dg.SelectedRows[i].DataBoundItem).Row;

    return rows;
}
```

This is generic so that you can return a typed data row using Typed Datasets.  You could make yours just return a `DataRow[]` if you wanted.  This also assumes that your DataGridView has a `DataView` bound to it.